# Проблема с кодировкой в Java-сервлете

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, servlet

При выполнении запроса на сервер (Spring Boot, Jetty, Spring MVC) приходит JSON.
Та часть запроса, что написана латиницей воспринимается правильно, вместо же кириллицы - коды юникода, через \u
В общем, сервер принимает следующего вида текст:

```
{"update_id":523075097,"message":{"message_id":114,"from":{"id":34080460},
"text":"\u0442\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0442 test \u0442\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0442"}}
```

Абсолютно вся латиница воспринимается адекватно
Метод, что получает код, выглядит так:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public void listen(HttpServletRequest req) throws IOException {
    String x = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(req.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
            .lines().reduce((s1, s2) -> s1 + s2).orElse("");
    TelegramInputParser.analyze(x);
}
```

Есть ли способы получать правильные тексты или быстро перевести строку в нормальную кодировку?

P.S. Пробовал в начале делать req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8), безуспешно

Comment: Покажите код, который этот JSON формирует.

Comment: Увы, формирует код сервер telegram, я лишь через Spring MVC принимаю запрос

Answer (score 0):

Проблемы с кодировкой нет, это просто такой формат. На сколько я понимаю, сложности с ним у вас возникают где-то в другом участке кода. Видимо там, где происходит вывод пользователю поля `text`. Перед выводом вы можете его преобразовать следующим образом:

```
new String(text.getBytes("utf-8"), "utf-8")
```